# jQuery load raw image from .php file, how to include

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, image

I have a page with some pictures drawn in php. I load a file with the reference-ids. Then the page is done loading, each of the image-elements will be loaded using ajax. (for example ajax_image.php?url=http://www.opti.com/1). Ajax_image then draws a image and outputs it using header jpeg.

The problem is that when I try to "include" or show this picture in my reference-file the output is not a picture, it's text saying:
`�JPEG`

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_picture.php?url="+escape($('#bilde1').attr('rel')),
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $('#bilde1').html(html);
        alert('Picture 1 loaded');
        sizeChangeCallback();
    }
});
```

I assume I get this problem because I use html to include the picture in the reference-file. But I have no idea what function to use, in order for it to understand that it's a raw picturefile.

Comment: Doesn't seem a correct way to solve your problem. What are trying to do? Do you want something like loading an image on demand ? <a onclick="$('<img src="ajax_picture.php?url=\"" + somefunction() + "\" />).insertAfter($(this))">Load a image on click next to this link</a>

Comment: So, another thing, the ajax call, will return a HttpResponse to be loaded on the HTML, this is loaded as text for that purpose. You may change to get the src to the image, instead of the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ajax for this.  Instead, simply output an `<img>` tag like this:

```
var imgTag = '<img src="ajax_picture.php?url=' + escape($('#bilde1').attr('rel')) + '" />';
$('#bilde1').html(imgTag);
```

Comment: Safer to use the `attr()` method which will automatically escape any nasty characters

Comment: ah, brilliant. Let me test that. EDIT: Worked as a sharm, thank you!